# Bootstrap quebra de linha

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Estou montando uma modal em bootstrap e dentro dela utilizando um formulário.

com as `<div class="form-group">` dentro de cada uma dessas monto um grid, com col-xs- que a somatória da 12 (um com 2, 2 e 8) mas mesmo assim estão 'encavalando' um input no outro.
O que faço de errado? não é só somar 12 e boa?

Ex: do código:
https://jsfiddle.net/dorathoto/8dsnmqeu/

Comment: No BS cada linha com as 12 colunas é definida dentro de uma `div` com classe `row`. Talvez seja isso que esteja resultando no encavalamento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A configuração de uma linha no Bootstrap deve ficar dentro de uma `div` com classe `row`. Assim garante que não há quebra dentro daquela linha de acordo com a largura. Da forma como você definiu como se fosse uma única linha, a adaptação da resolução pode se perder.

Outra informação importante é sobre o `form-group` que deve englobar um input ou label + input conforme é explicado na [documentação](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms).

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-filtro"><i class="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i> Filtros </button>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal-filtro" tabindex="-1">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Filtros</h3>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">            
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
     <div class="form-group">
      <div class="onoffswitch">
       <input type="checkbox" name="chkBairro" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="chkBairro">
       <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="chkBairro">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
       </label>
      </div>
     </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">Bairros</div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
     <select class="form-control">
      <option>Selecione</option>
      <option>Lorem</option>
      <option>Lorem</option>
     </select>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
     <div class="onoffswitch form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="chkEquipes" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="chkEquipes">
      <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="chkEquipes">
       <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
       <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
      </label>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">Equipes Policiais</div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
     <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control">
       <option>Selecione</option>
       <option>Lorem</option>
       <option>Lorem</option>
      </select>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
     <div class="onoffswitch form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="chkEquipes1" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="chkEquipes1">
      <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="chkEquipes1">
       <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
       <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
      </label>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">Equipes Policiais</div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
     <select class="form-control">
      <option>Selecione</option>
      <option>Lorem</option>
      <option>Lorem</option>
     </select>
    </div>
   </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Filtrar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```